# window.pageYOffset getting wrong values on iPad

Tags: javascript, css, ipad

I have a header floater which disappears as soon as you scroll down the page. works fine, just not on my iPad.

When I scroll up the page the navigation menu appears as expected, but as soon as I let go of the page it disappears again. it also appears when the page hits the bottom

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Our Funky HTML Page</title>
<meta name="description" content="Our first page">
<meta name="keywords" content="html tutorial template">
<style>
    .main-header {
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        background-color: #ffff00;
        padding: 0.5rem 2.0rem 0.5rem 1.9rem;
        height: 7.0rem;
        z-index: 50;
        display: flex;
        margin: auto;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        transition: top 0.4s; /* Transition effect when sliding down (and up) */
        }

        .content {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #ff0000;
            height: 2000px;
        }
</style>
<script>

    var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
    window.onscroll = function() {
      var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
      //  if ( ( (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos)  ||  ( currentScrollPos < 50 )  ) ){
      if ( ( (prevScrollpos >= currentScrollPos)    ) ){
        document.getElementById("main-header").style.top = "0rem";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("main-header").style.top = "-8rem"; // "-70px";
      }
      prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
    }


</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-header" id="main-header"></div>
    <div class="content" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

the site is done in vuejs

the relevant part:

```
   <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Our Funky HTML Page</title>
<meta name="description" content="Our first page">
<meta name="keywords" content="html tutorial template">
<style>
    .main-header {
        width: 100%;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        background-color: #ffff00;
        padding: 0.5rem 2.0rem 0.5rem 1.9rem;
        height: 7.0rem;
        z-index: 50;
        display: flex;
        margin: auto;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        transition: top 0.4s; /* Transition effect when sliding down (and up) */
        }

        .content {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #ff0000;
            height: 2000px;
        }
</style>
<script>

    var prevScrollpos = window.pageYOffset;
    window.onscroll = function() {
      var currentScrollPos = window.pageYOffset;
      //  if ( ( (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos)  ||  ( currentScrollPos < 50 )  ) ){
      if ( ( (prevScrollpos >= currentScrollPos)    ) ){
        document.getElementById("main-header").style.top = "0rem";
      } else {
        document.getElementById("main-header").style.top = "-8rem"; 
     
      }
      prevScrollpos = currentScrollPos;
    }
    
    
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main-header" id="main-header">

    </div>

    <div class="content" >

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can  you make your code into a runnable snippet so we can see the problem - it makes it much easier to help. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Could you describe in more detail exactly when  you want the header to reappear. Is it as soon as there is some scrolling up or when the scrolling gets to the top of the page again? I think the iPad problem is related to the disappearance/reappearance of part of the browser bar on scrolling.

Comment: ok, when the user scrolls down, the header disappears. when the user scrolls up the header reappears. works fine, but not on iOS.  I can fix this with  if ( ( (prevScrollpos > currentScrollPos)  ||  ( currentScrollPos < 50 ) ) ) ){ ...   and when the user scrolls down to the end of the page the header is shown on the iPad.

Comment: I edited the question, now it contains a quick & dirty html file

Comment: Please make your code into a runnable snippet - otherwise I can't test it on an iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have struggled with this issue for a while so here is what I have found:

The problem is that on iOS page bounces on top and bottom edges so the window.pageYOffset values could be negative as well as larger than actual page height. Thus the `prevScrollpos >= currentScrollPos` condition is not sufficient.

- One solution is to disable bounce effect by adding `overscroll-behavior: none;` to html element.
- Proper solution is to extend conditions to edge cases:

```js
const maxScrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
if (prevScrollpos >= currentScrollPos && currentScrollPos < maxScrollHeight) { // Prevent hiding header on bottom overscroll
  document.getElementById("main-header").style.top = "0rem";
} else if (currentScrollPos > 0) { // Prevent hiding header on top overscroll
  document.getElementById("main-header").style.top = "-8rem";
}
```